# Is it possible to shorten the solution for this 2014 RMO question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, contest-math, alternative-proof

I was solving a question from the Regional Math Olympiad (RMO) 2014.

> Find all positive real numbers $x,y,z$ such that
>
> $$2x-2y+\frac1z=\frac1{2014},\quad2y-2z+\frac1x=\frac1{2014},\quad2z-2x+\frac1y=\frac1{2014}$$

---

Here's my solution:

These expressions are cyclic. Therefore all solution sets must be unordered. This implies that $x=y=z$.

Thus, $x=2014$ and the solution is

$$x=2014\quad y=2014\quad z=2014$$

---

Here's the official solution:

Adding the three equations, we get $$\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z=\frac3{2014}$$

We can also write them as  $$2xz-2yz+1=\frac z{2014},\quad2xy-2xz+1=\frac x{2014},\quad2yz-2xy+1=\frac y{2014}$$

Adding these, we get $$x+y+z=3\times2014$$

Therefore, $$\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)(x+y+z)=9$$

Using $\text{AM-GM}$ inequality, we therefore obtain $$9=\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)(x+y+z)\ge9\times(xyz)^{\frac13}\left({1\over xyz}\right)^{\frac13}=9$$

Hence equality holds and we conclude that $x=y=z$.

Thus we conclude $$x=2014\quad y=2014\quad z=2014$$

---

What I wonder is if there is something wrong with my approach. If yes, what is it? If no, then why is the official solution so long winded?

Comment: What exactly is a "solution set" and what does it mean for a solution set to be unordered? If a "solution set" is a set, then of course it is "unordered" because all sets are. Why would this imply that $x=y=z$?

Comment: The meaning I took was that the solution set is invariant under permutations; i.e., if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, then so is $(\sigma(x),\sigma(y),\sigma(z))$ for any $\sigma\in S_3$...

Comment: Of course, that fact does not imply that $x=y=z$, but I took that to be an understandable reasoning error.

Comment: @littleO For example, the system of equations $x+2y=3,x+y=2.5$ has solution $x=2,y=\frac12$. If I exchanged these values, then they would not satisfy the equation. Which means that the (ordered) solution set is $[1,0.5]$. A solution set is unordered if all possible permutations of it satisfy the equations.

Comment: Any solution of $(x-2y)(y-2x)=0$, if permuted, results in another solution. That doesn't mean we can conclude that $x=y$. It just means our solution set is symmetric across the line $x=y$.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Of course, but you have only one equation here. What I  said in my solution was that if the solution set for a system of $n$ equations in $n$ variables was unordered, it implied that all unknowns had equal value.

Comment: That's still a claim that would require proof.

Comment: Would $x+y+z=4$ be a counterexample to your logic?

Comment: Perhaps $x+y = 2$, $2x + 2y = 4$ would be a counterexample -- that's two equations in 2 unknowns, but it has solutions with $x \ne y$.

Comment: see https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975573 entitled "Do symmetric problems have symmetric solutions?"

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Consider the system of equations

$xy + z = 1, \quad yz + x = 1, \quad zx + y = 1$

These equations are related by cyclic permutations of $(x,y,z)$, but they are satisified by $(1,1,0)$ (and its cyclic permutations) when $x$, $y$ and $z$ are not all equal.

There are also solutions where $x=y=z=\frac{\pm \sqrt{5}-1}{2}$, but these are not the *only* solutions.

Comment: Ah. Of course. I didn't realize that. However, the question asks for positive reals. Could you provide an example where the solution set is wholly positive and unordered, but where the unknowns aren't equal?

Comment: How about the same left-hand sides, but they're all equal to $3$? Then every permutation of $(1,1,2)$ works.

Answer (score 13):

As Mohammad Riazi-Kermani and gandalf61 show, you cannot conclude $x=y=z$ simply from the cyclic invariance of the system of equations.  However, in this case you *can* make a simple argument that starts with an observation based on cyclic invariance, namely that you may as well assume $x\ge y,z$ (i.e., cycle through $(x,y,z)$, $(y,z,x)$ and $(z,x,y)$ and pick the one that starts with the largest of the three numbers).

If $x\ge y,z$, then $2x-2y\ge0$ while $2z-2x\le0$, so that

$${1\over2014}=2x-2y+{1\over z}\ge{1\over z}\implies z\ge2014$$

and

$${1\over2014}=2z-2x+{1\over y}\le{1\over y}\implies 2014\ge y$$

so we now have $x\ge z\ge 2014\ge y$. But this now tells us $2y-2z\le0$, so that

$${1\over2014}=2y-2z+{1\over x}\le{1\over x}\implies2014\ge x$$

so we now have $2014\ge x\ge z\ge 2014\ge y$, from which we see $x=z=2014\ge y$. The final equality, $2014=y$, comes by sustituting $x=z=2014$ into any of the three equations.

Note, the implication ${1\over2014}\ge{1\over z}\implies z\ge2014$ requires the assumption $z\gt0$.

Answer (score 8):

The equations being cyclic does not necessarily mean the variables  are equal.

For example $$ x+y+z=6\\x^2+y^2+z^2=14\\x^3+y^3+z^3=36$$ Solutions are not equal. $$x=1, y=2,z=3$$ is one solutions set.

Comment: This isn't cyclic. Cyclic would be $3x^3+2y^2+z=11,3y^3+2z^2+x=11,3z^3+2x^2+y=11$. What I mean by cyclic is that you can just shift the places of the variables one to the left or one to the right to get another one of the given equations.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo Thanks for the comment. That is quite  different from what I was thinking.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo That's  not the standard definition of "cyclic".

Answer (score 2):

The general cyclic system is
$$ f(x,y,z)=f(y,z,x)=f(z,x,y)=0$$
with some function $f$. There is not the slightest reason to assume that $f(42,\pi,e)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

First, your use of the word "cyclic" isn't quite consistent with its usual meaning.

Second, a counterexample:

xy+z=0

yz+x = 0

zx+y = 0

(1,1,-1) satisfies these equations.